# STS : Imported projects are showing compilation error with triangle symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, ant, spring-tool-suite

I have imported existing ant projects to my work space. I am getting compilation error  error along with some red color triangle in my project.
What this red color triangle indicates ? and how to fix this?[STS: Project  error in triangle indication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDh5h.png)

Comment: Have you read the error message inside the "Problems" view ?

Comment: Yes, I read the error. All are related to class not found!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be a compilation issue or some required hybris dependency isn't imported.

Try refreshing all projects in Eclipse and rebuilding (including the hybris platform). Take a look at the 'Problems' tab then and work through the issues one by one.

It looks to me like you're working through the hybris release 5 trails too. Try taking a look at https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Trail+~+Preparation#Trail~Preparation-SettinguptheEclipseWorkspace and https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Eclipse+workspace+errors+-+A+Complete+guide

Comment: Mike, Thanks for your reply! Shall look into the links.

Answer (score 0):

Red color triangle indicates the possible exceptions at runtime. Since I have installed PMD plugin into my eclipse I am getting this.

And PMD warnings can be removed by adding the following annotations

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unused","PMD"})
```